# When I switch on my laptop the wifi adapter is not found, after restarting the laptop it is found

Tags: wireless, adapter, additional-drivers

The wifi adapter is not found after first switching on the laptop, after restarting the laptop the wifi driver is found and the laptop is able to connect to the wifi. This happens every time I turn on the laptop, is there a way to fix this?

**context:**
I installed ubuntu 22.04 on an old lenovo yoga 510, switching from windows 10. Using lspci I can see the driver is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac wireless Network Adapter (rev 30).

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.Look at your startup logs with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.